# Can a husband and wife combine their UK Standard Visitor visa applications?

Tags: application-status, mail, standard-visitor-visas

We applied for UK Standard Visitor visas as two separate applications.

After completing our biometrics do we need to send the applications with supporting documents as **two separate postal mails** for stamping or can we send it as one?

Also does the return label have to be **two different prepaid return shipping labels** or is one enough?

Answer (score 8):

You and your wife are both submitting applications for a Standard Visitor Visa and you are at the final stage (post biometrics).

> do we need to send the application with supporting documents as two
>   separate postal mails for stamping or can we send it as one?

You can send both applications in a single envelope. Before doing this you should make sure that each application has the other's GWF number on it. The mail room assistant and duty witness will know what to do when your envelope is opened.

> Also the return label has to be two different prepaid return shipping
>   labels or one is enough?

No, one is not enough. Two separate prepaid labels should be created, one for each application.  Decisions may be made at different times and evidence may be separated for detailed examination. Consular personnel are smart enough to combine bundles, but Proviso (i.e., their IT system) works best when applications have their own labels.

The *unasked question* is if you qualify for accelerated service, can it be combined across two applicants? No, just the primary should opt for accelerated service. That's enough to get the entire family a quick decision.