# UK Standard Visitor Visa from USA - What type of Return Shipping label should be purchased

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, shipping, return

I reviewed many answers and the following ones,
[Can a husband and wife combine their UK Standard Visitor visa applications?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/85638/can-a-husband-and-wife-combine-their-uk-standard-visitor-visa-applications)

The recommendations provided on the site, helped me with the fact that we need separate return label for each of the family member.  We are a family of 4 applying for UK Standard Visitor visa.  As per the instructions on the UK Visa site, we will be sending documents in the UPS  2nd day Air.

My question is on the Return Shipping label - Can I purchase UPS 2nd Day Ground for the return label or should the return label also be UPS 2nd Day (or Next day) Air?

The cost difference between ground and Air is big - Air is almost twice that off ground.  Looking for clarifications before buying the return shipping label.

Browsing this forum saved me a lot of time and anxiety.  Thanks much for providing the proper responses.

Answer (score 2):

The official UK government website for [applying for a UK visa from the USA](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa) states that ground service is not acceptable for the return shipping.

> To have your documents returned you must provide a fully addressed prepaid electronic shipping label (we cannot accept ground services and non-electronic waybills). Put your return shipping label and envelope inside the package, and keep a copy of the waybill for your records.

You will need to use an air service such as UPS 2nd Day Air for your return shipping labels that you include with your visa application. You can purchase these at a UPS/FedEx store, or if you have a UPS/FedEx account you can print them yourself.

You can send your application package to VFS via any means you wish; it does not have to be sent by air service. But it must be sent within 5 days after your biometrics appointment. But it is still a very good idea to use a tracked service such as USPS Priority Mail or UPS/FedEx.

> Your biometric confirmation receipt will be stamped at your appointment. You then have 5 days to mail this, your application form, your passport and supporting documents to VFS Services USA Inc. All applications must be accompanied by a valid passport with at least one page blank on both sides. If the application is mailed without a passport the application will be refused.
>
> You should mail your application to:
>
> VFS Services USA Inc.
>   UKVI Scanning Hub
>   80 Broad Street
>   Floor 6
>   New York, 10004